# Conditional probability in Heckman model

Tags: conditional-probability

Two regressions:
$$
y_{1i}=x_i\beta+u_{1i}
$$
$$
y_{2i}=z_i\gamma+u_{2i}
$$
Two errors are correlated. $x_i$ and $z_i$ I suppose are not necessarily independent (but it is not so clear from my lecture notes).

Some background: The two regressions are used to correct sample selection bias, and used in the Heckman model.

The notes say to get the following conditional probability:
\begin{align}
f(y_{1i},z_i\gamma+u_{2i}>0|x_i, z_i ) &= f(y_{1i}|x_i, z_i)Pr(z_i\gamma+u_{2i}>0|y_{1i}, x_i, z_i) \\
&= f(y_{1i}|x_i)Pr(z_i\gamma+u_{2i}>0|u_{1i}, x_i, z_i) \\
&=f(u_{1i})\int^{\infty}_{-z_i\gamma}f(u_{2i}|u_{1i})du_{2i}
\end{align}
I don't understand how $z_i$ disappear $f(y_{1i}|x_i)$, and why $f(y_{1i}|x_i)=f(x_i\beta+u_{1i}|x_i)=f(u_{1i})$.